# Creating log file on windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, logfiles

I'm writing a program on windows mobile 6 in C# and I want it to collect data from GPS-module every second. What is the simplest way to store it on the phone? I'm thinking about either txt or XML file. What do you recommend?

Comment: use xml it's better in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a txt file since you can just continuously append to the end.

Going the XML route will require more space and more processing since you can't just seek to the end and append data.